# License Plate Factory

Tags: java

I'm having problems with a concept utilizing program in my Java class, its supposed to be relatively simple but I find it difficult.

"Write a class LicensePlateFactory that generates license 
plates.  Provide a method getNextPlate that returns a unique 
license plate number (an int).  Use sequential numbers for all 
license plates created by the LicencePlateFactory, starting from 
100001.

Write a program that creates a LicensePlateFactory, then 
obtains from it and displays a dozen consecutive license plates."

My code(looks bad, didn't know what to do after staring at the problem for quite a while):
The factory:

```
public class LicensePlateFactory 
{
    private int k = 100001;
    private int count;

    public LicensePlateFactory(int x)
    {
          this.count++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    getnextPlate();
    }

    public int getnextPlate()
    {   
    return k + count;

    }
}
```

The program that creates the factory:

```
public class LicensePlateFactoryRunner 
{

    private LicensePlateFactory fac;
    public LicensePlateFactoryRunner()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 13; x++)
        {
        LicensePlateFactory fac = new LicensePlateFactory();
                    System.out.println(LicensePlateFactory.getnextPlate());
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps I am forgetting some basic java concepts?

Comment: Should this be tagged 'homework' perhaps?

Comment: @Peter: [The homework tag is officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: @user: It seems like you've thrown some code together which has the beginnings of making some sense.  But parts of the code just make no sense, and I wonder if you've tried to explain to yourself, in plain English, what this code does.  For example, why do you think you need to create 12 `LicensePlateFactory`s?

Comment: The assignment said to create 12 license plates.  And it is homework, I'll add the tag.  I also got the program working, but I'm not sure it is that efficient. I'll add in the new code.

Comment: @user: I understand you need 12 license plates.  If you need 12 cars in real life, do you need to build 12 factories to make them?  Or do you need one factory that you can then build 12 cars from?

Comment: One factory that builds twelve license plate factories. But I think the program is worded strangely, the factory is supposed to be able to make license plates in general, in sequential order, starting from 100001, while the other program is supposed to obtain from license place factory to make 12 license plates.  I just used a repetition structure to build 12 license plate factories, each making one license plate, and I don't think that is the correct way.

Comment: Also, do all the car factories share a unique machine to build cars, or do thay all have their own machine? They all have their own machine. So the counter and the initial value (`k`) should not be static.

Comment: edited to delete statics, but now LicensePlateFactory.count++; states that it cannot make a static reference to a non-static method.  I also thought you use statics whenever accumulating an amount?

Comment: @user1629075 That is obvious, you are trying to access non-static variable in static way in your `LicensePlateFactory` constructor.

Comment: Since the count is the license factory's own count, you just need `this.count++`, or even `count++`. A field is static if the field is associated with the class itself (i.e. all instances of PlateFactory) and not with a specific instance of the class (i.e. one particular plate factory).

Comment: @user1629075 It doesn't matter wheather you are using `LicensePlateFactory` object or not. You cant not modify basic java rules. As JB Nizet said `LicensePlateFactory.count++` replace with `this.count++` or just with `count++`

Comment: So then to write a program to create a license plate factory, would it be something like: LicensePlateFactory fac = new LicensePlateFactory(); ? I already had that in my code but the compiler said it was never used.

Comment: @user1629075 Becuse when you are creating instance for facroty you are not passing anything so you program considering super or default constructor. If you want to talk more come in java chat room.

Comment: @MarkPeters: The deprecation may be "official", but that doesn't make it right. I've watched Help Vampires destroy many communities over the years, and it's happening to SO. But the Book has been closed on this topic by TPTB, so ....

Comment: @Peter: I wasn't trying to argue for or against ; merely noting the OP couldn't add the tag even if he or you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going to display the same license plate 12 times.  The reason is because you're creating a new `LicensePlateFactory` for every iteration of the loop.  What you should do is move the creation of the factory to outside the loop.

Also, and this is a minor quibble, but usually loops start with 0 unless you have a really good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

1. Create the `PlateFactory` class with one field: the last used plate number and one method: `getNextPlate()` returning a `Plate`
2. Introduce a `Plate` object with one field: plate number, as this object cannot be instantiated (assumed) without using the factory, it should have no public constructor. We can also assume the plate number cannot be changed (final field, no setter).
3. Create an `App` class for your `main()` method and in this method create the `PlateFactory` instance, then use this instance 12 times to create 12 `Plate` (with number 100001, 100002, ... but the factory handles that).

Some reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Java_3